# Regular expression in Actionscript (bug?)

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, flash

I am using following regular expression to clean user input:

```
new RegExp("[^A-Za-z_0-9]", "gi")
```

However, one of the user is by passing this regular expression by inputting a special character that causes crashing of flash. Is there any special character (or unicode _ ) that this regular expression won't recognize?

Comment: Somthing like this \\?

Comment: _ is intentionally bypassed right?

Comment: Everything that is not a number or a character (a, b, c) For example: space, new line, tab, !@#$%^ etc. What are you trying to achieve? You may use a online tool for checking your regular expresion like http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: I am trying to clean text and remove all the special characters. However, someone is intentionally bypassing and adding some special character. I am not sure what that character is. It is causing flash to crash.

Comment: @vks this regular expression can recognize \\? and remove it.

Comment: Did you try to use a regex like `/[^0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]+/g` or escaping every character you want as hex? This is a really strange behavior since: `[^\w\d]+` and global modifier should be all you need.

Comment: What do you mean by excaping Hex? What characters can bypass this regular expression?

Comment: [\W_]+
  look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar_non.asp